# webpages_UsersInRoles missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 together with SimpleMemmbership.

When I built my application the following tables were built automatically

webpages_Membership

webpages_OAuthMembership

webpages_Roles

I can successfully register users.

However, the **webpages_UsersInRoles** table seems to be missing.

Does anyone know why this table is missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This article](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model) might assist you in resolving your issue.

**Update:**

The article above got us going in the right direction. Our solution was to add a definition for "webpages_UsersInRoles to our UserProfile.cs class that gets used during initialization (we are doing code first).

```
   [Table("UserProfile")]
public  class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}



[Table("webpages_Membership")]
public class Membership
{
    public Membership()
    {
        //Roles = new List<Role>();
        OAuthMemberships = new List<OAuthMembership>();
        UsersInRoles = new List<UsersInRole>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    public bool? IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }
    public int PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(128)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(128)]
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ICollection<OAuthMembership> OAuthMemberships { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ICollection<UsersInRole> UsersInRoles { get; set; }
}

[Table("webpages_OAuthMembership")]
public class OAuthMembership
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), StringLength(30)]
    public string Provider { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), StringLength(100)]
    public string ProviderUserId { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Column("UserId"), InverseProperty("OAuthMemberships")]
    public Membership User { get; set; }
}

[Table("webpages_UsersInRoles")]
public class UsersInRole
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Column("RoleId"), InverseProperty("UsersInRoles")]
    public Role Roles { get; set; }

    [Column("UserId"), InverseProperty("UsersInRoles")]
    public Membership Members { get; set; }



}

[Table("webpages_Roles")]
public class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        UsersInRoles = new List<UsersInRole>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    //public ICollection<Membership> Members { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public ICollection<UsersInRole> UsersInRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Then on the class that inherits dbContext we added the public DbSet UsersInRoles { get; set; }.

```
  public class IntranetEntities : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UsersInRole> UsersInRoles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {

        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;

    }
}
```

We then proceeded to build our project and using the VS package manager console we executed (since we are doing code first development)

> update-database -verbose

[image: webpages_UsersInRoles]

The model was then updated to our expectations. I have provided all the required code in the hopes it saves someone in the future time and grief.

Comment: Hi, I just implemented your model and as soon as I try to assign a role to a user i get The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles_dbo.webpages_Membership_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "PCSPI", table "dbo.webpages_Membership", column 'UserId'.
The statement has been terminated. Do you what could be the problem?

Comment: No, I have not encountered that issue. Can you post the error stack trace?