# SimpleMembership Could not drop constraint

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, simplemembership

**When executing:**

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles_dbo.webpages_Membership_UserId]
```

**I receive an error:**

```
'FK_dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles_dbo.webpages_Membership_UserId' is not a constraint.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

**This is my `webpages_UsersInRoles` table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles] (
    [UserId] INT NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [RoleId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId]),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[webpages_Roles] ([RoleId])
);
```

I tried doing following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012612/webpages-usersinroles-missing), but it didn't work for me.

Comment: The error seems fairly self explanatory. `[FK_dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles_dbo.webpages_Membership_UserId]` is not a constraint, the two constraints in the table are `fk_UserUd` and `fk_RoleId`. What constraint are you trying to drop?

Comment: Im trying to recreate the UsersInRoles with this

   [Table("webpages_UsersInRoles")]
    public class UsersInRole
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Column("RoleId"), InverseProperty("UsersInRoles")]
        public Role Roles { get; set; }

        [Column("UserId"), InverseProperty("UsersInRoles")]
        public Membership Members { get; set; }
    }

I should just have run, but it wont because of the constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(int id)
{
    var tmpuser = "";
    var ctx = new UsersContext();
    using (ctx)
    {
        var firstOrDefault   = ctx.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(us => us.UserId==id);
        if (firstOrDefault != null)
            tmpuser = firstOrDefault.UserName;
    }

    string[] allRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(tmpuser);
    Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(tmpuser,allRoles);

    //Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(tmpuser, "RoleName");

    ((SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).DeleteAccount(tmpuser);
    Membership.Provider.DeleteUser(tmpuser, true);
    Membership.DeleteUser(tmpuser, true);

    ctx = new UsersContext();

    return View(ctx.UserProfiles.OrderBy(user => user.UserName).ToList());
}
```