# query webpages_Membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, code-first, simplemembership

I'm using the MVC4 Internet Application Code First.  I was wondering if there is a way for me to retrieve the `PasswordVerificationToken` from the `webpages_Membership` table. I've tried following instructions in [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012612/webpages-usersinroles-missing).

I'm able to retrieve the `PasswordVerificationToken` from the `webpages_Membership` table however when I try to add a user to a role using `Roles.AddUserToRole` I get a foreign key constraint error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't matter just added the simple membership tables to an entity model